The keyword property of chrome_settings_overrides.search_provider doesn't seem to do anything
I'm trying to build a simple chrome extension that acts as a search engine for YouTube. I want to be able to type in yt/search query and have it search youtube for "search query". The issue is that the keyword doesn't really do anything. If I set is_default to true then every search query I do (even the ones without the keyword) searches YouTube. But if I set is_default to false, the keyword does nothing. So what's the point of the keyword if it doesn't do anything? Thanks for the help!
This is my manifest:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "YouTube Search",
    "description": "Allows you to easily search YouTube without visiting the site",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "redirector.html",
        "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation",
        "search"
    ],
    "chrome_settings_overrides": {
        "search_provider": {
            "name": "YouTube Search",
            "keyword": "yt",
            "search_url": "https://youtube.com/results?search_query={searchTerms}",
            "favicon_url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#/media/File:Apple_logo_black.svg",
            "encoding": "UTF-8",
            "is_default": false
        }
    }
}

I tried setting is_default to true and false. I was expecting it to check for the keyword if is_default is false and search YouTube. But it still just searches Google.
Also, background.js is empty. There's nothing there. Just thought I should bring it up.

It may be a bug, but even if not it doesn't make a lot of sense because Chrome automatically creates searches for sites that the user can activate in browser settings. For an extension it would make more sense to use chrome.omnibox API to provide dynamic suggestions while the user types the query.

I actually wanted to use both this and the omnibus. Mostly because I want to be able to type yt/search_query to search and also do ytsearch_query which is what the omnibus would use. It feels more flexible that way. But yeah this does sound like a bug. I think for now I’ll keep it as just an omnibus. Thanks!
